# Quaternion rotation works fine with y/z rotation but gets messed up when I add x rotation

Tags: c++, math, rotation, quaternions

So I've been learning about quaternions recently and decided to make my own implementation. I tried to make it simple but I still can't pinpoint my error. x/y/z axis rotation works fine on it's own and y/z rotation work as well, but the second I add x axis to any of the others I get a strange stretching output. I'll attach the important code for the rotations below:(Be warned I'm quite new to cpp).

Here is how I describe a quaternion (as I understand since they are unit quaternions imaginary numbers aren't required):

```cpp
struct Quaternion {
    float w, x, y, z;
};
```

The multiplication rules of quaternions:

```cpp
Quaternion operator* (Quaternion n, Quaternion p) {
    Quaternion o;

    // implements quaternion multiplication rules:
    o.w = n.w * p.w - n.x * p.x - n.y * p.y - n.z * p.z;
    o.x = n.w * p.x + n.x * p.w + n.y * p.z - n.z * p.y;
    o.y = n.w * p.y - n.x * p.z + n.y * p.w + n.z * p.x;
    o.z = n.w * p.z + n.x * p.y - n.y * p.x + n.z * p.w;

    return o;
}
```

Generating the rotation quaternion to multiply the total rotation by:

```cpp
Quaternion rotate(float w, float x, float y, float z) {
    Quaternion n;

    n.w = cosf(w/2);
    n.x = x * sinf(w/2);
    n.y = y * sinf(w/2);
    n.z = z * sinf(w/2); 

    return n;
}
```

And finally, the matrix calculations which turn the quaternion into an x/y/z position:

```cpp
inline vector<float> quaternion_matrix(Quaternion total, vector<float> vec) {
    float x = vec[0], y = vec[1], z = vec[2];

    // implementation of 3x3 quaternion rotation matrix:
    vec[0] = (1 - 2 * pow(total.y, 2) - 2 * pow(total.z, 2))*x + (2 * total.x * total.y - 2 * total.w * total.z)*y + (2 * total.x * total.z + 2 * total.w * total.y)*z;
    vec[1] = (2 * total.x * total.y + 2 * total.w * total.z)*x + (1 - 2 * pow(total.x, 2) - 2 * pow(total.z, 2))*y + (2 * total.y * total.z + 2 * total.w * total.x)*z;
    vec[2] = (2 * total.x * total.z - 2 * total.w * total.y)*x + (2 * total.y * total.z - 2 * total.w * total.x)*y + (1 - 2 * pow(total.x, 2) - 2 * pow(total.y, 2))*z;

    return vec;
}
```

That's pretty much it (I also have a normalize function to deal with floating point errors), I initialize all objects quaternion to: w = 1, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0. I rotate a quaternion using an expression like this:

```cpp
obj.rotation = rotate(angle, x-axis, y-axis, z-axis) * obj.rotation
```

where obj.rotation is the objects total quaternion rotation value.

I appreciate any help I can get on this issue, if anyone knows what's wrong or has also experienced this issue before. Thanks

EDIT: multiplying total by these quaternions output the expected rotation:

```cpp
rotate(angle,1,0,0)
rotate(angle,0,1,0)
rotate(angle,0,0,1)
rotate(angle,0,1,1)
```

However, any rotations such as these make the model stretch oddly:

```cpp
rotate(angle,1,1,0)
rotate(angle,1,0,1)
```

EDIT2: here is the normalize function I use to normalize the quaternions:

```
Quaternion normalize(Quaternion n, double tolerance) {
    // adds all squares of quaternion values, if normalized, total will be 1:
    double total = pow(n.w, 2) + pow(n.x, 2) + pow(n.y, 2) + pow(n.z, 2);
    if (total > 1 + tolerance || total < 1 - tolerance) {
        // normalizes value of quaternion if it exceeds a certain tolerance value:
        n.w /= (float) sqrt(total);
        n.x /= (float) sqrt(total);
        n.y /= (float) sqrt(total);
        n.z /= (float) sqrt(total);
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Example test cases that fail? Is the vector `[x,y,z]` in `rotate` normalized?

Comment: for all my test cases so far, he values of ```[x,y,z]``` have all been 1 or 0 as the vector describes the axis being rotated about and ```w``` describes the angle. I have updated the post to add test cases which work and fail

Comment: The example values you provided, `[1,1,0]` and `[1,0,1]`, are *not* normalized, and consequently nor are the quaternions created by `rotate()`. They should be `[√½,√½,0]` and `[√½,0,√½]` respectively.

Comment: I edited my post to include the normalization function I use. Should I normalize the input or output for the rotate function?

Comment: The magnitude of the output quaternion will be a function of the rotation angle if the axis is not normalized, leading to incorrect scaling of each component. Therefore the input axis should always be normalized first.

Comment: I feel like that isn't the issue as rotate(angle,0,1,1) works. I tried normalizing the input but it didn't change the output. I'm going to go over the quaternion multiplication and matrix to see if I made a typo or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement two rotations *in sequence* you need the quaternion product of the two elementary rotations. Each elementary rotation is specified by an axis and an angle. But in your code you did not make sure you have a unit vector (direction vector) for the axis.

Do the following modification

```
Quaternion rotate(float w, float x, float y, float z) {
    Quaternion n;
    float f = 1/sqrtf(x*x+y*y+z*z)

    n.w = cosf(w/2);
    n.x = f * x * sinf(w/2);
    n.y = f * y * sinf(w/2);
    n.z = f * z * sinf(w/2); 

    return n;
}
```

and then use it as follows

```
Quaternion n = rotate(angle1,1,0,0) * rotate(angle2,0,1,0)
```

for the combined rotation of `angle1` about the *x*-axis, and `angle2` about the *y*-axis.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, you are not initializing your quaternions correctly.

The following quaternions are not rotations:

```
rotate(angle,0,1,1)
rotate(angle,1,1,0)
rotate(angle,1,0,1)
```

The reason is the axis is not normalized e.g., the vector (0,1,1) is not normalized. Also make sure your angles are in radians.